# Slow Keys at log-in screen means I can't access laptop!

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I have a Macbook Air that's less than a year old and woke up today to an issue.

When logging in, I have to hold each key down for 3 seconds before it'll recognise that I'm pressing it - so it'll end up writing four of the same letter in my password and I have to strategically hold down the backspace for 3 seconds to delete the three extra letters. As you can imagine, it took me about 15 minutes to get it right and actually get in to my laptop.

I followed all the advice on other blogs - the issue is completely gone when I boot in safe mode so it's not a hardware issue as far as I can tell. I did a clean install of OS and problem persisted.

The Slow Keys checkbox is unticked so I just have no idea why this is happening.

I should not that once logged in, the keyboard works perfectly fine!

Any and all advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tested to see what happens when you use an external keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

If you did a clean install, that would suggest a hardware issue. It's possible you've got a corrupt install media, too. This can happen if you've created a USB flash drive installer and the USB drive you have doesn't like the block size you've specified (or the default) when using the *dd* command.

Don't forget to reset the PRAM, as well as the SMC. Apple's instructions:

1. Shut down your Mac.
2. Find Command (⌘), Option, P, and R on your keyboard.
3. Turn on your Mac.
4. Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys immediately after you
   hear the startup sound.
5. Hold these keys until the computer restarts and you hear the startup
   sound for a second time.
6. Release the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I know you say the issue is not replicated when booted into Safe Mode, but have you tried resetting the SMC anyway?

For MacBook Airs here’s the procedure for resetting the SMC:

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the MagSafe adapter (or power cable) **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you all are doing well.

I was also facing the same issue.
Today when I turned on my MacBook pro M1 Chip It showed on the screen that the **Sticky keys on**, the **slow keys on**, and the mouse keys on.
I could not type the password as the slow keys function is on but the more horrible thing was that the "mouse keys" within the keyboard were also on.
When the mouse keys function is on then some keyboard button works to move the arrow up, down, left, and right. So if keyboard buttons(O,K,L, M and some more keys) are working like a mouse to move arrow then how I can type my password?
Also when the "slow keys" is on then you have to press each button for 2 to 3 seconds to type the password but if "mouse button" is also on then you can not type your password because some buttons are working to move the mouse arrow.

It took the whole day for me to solve this.
I restarted my pc and as it showed the login screen I quickly typed the password before my laptop make the turn on those slow keys, mouse keys, and sticky keys.

And as I got success into the login then I searched on the internet but I did not get any solution.
Then I was just checking settings and then I went into System Setting ==> Lock Screen ==> Accessibility Options. There I saw that slow keys, sticky keys, and mouse keys were all options enabled for the lock screen. I disabled them and now the problem is solved.

And sorry, I am not good in explaining things as English is not my first language
Thanks :)